# Swift3 : how to handle precedencegroup now operator should be declare with a body?

Tags: swift, operators, swift3, xcode8-beta6

Former Swift 3 code for operator was:

```
infix operator × {associativity left precedence 150}
```

But now, as per Xcode 8 beta 6, this generate the following warning:

```
"operator should not be declared with body"
```

What's the right way to use precedencegroup predicate as no doc exists right now?

I have tried this, but does not work:

```
infix operator × : times
precedencegroup times {
     associativity: left 
     precedence: 150
}
```

Comment: Checkout apple code, may be this will help: https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/3d005f3ad90f041325e7a28fd9d0544324ac24d6/test/Parse/operator_decl.swift

Answer (score 60, accepted):

As per [SE-0077](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0077-operator-precedence.md), the precedence of an operator is no longer determined by a magic number – instead you now use the `higherThan` and (if the group resides in another module) `lowerThan`  `precedencegroup` relationships in order to define precedence relative to other groups.

For example (from the [evolution proposal](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0077-operator-precedence.md)):

> ```
> // module Swift
> precedencegroup Additive { higherThan: Range }
> precedencegroup Multiplicative { higherThan: Additive }
>
> // module A
> precedencegroup Equivalence {
>   higherThan: Comparative
>   lowerThan: Additive  // possible, because Additive lies in another module
> }
> infix operator ~ : Equivalence
>
> 1 + 2 ~ 3    // same as (1 + 2) ~ 3, because Additive > Equivalence
> 1 * 2 ~ 3    // same as (1 * 2) ~ 3, because Multiplicative > Additive > Equivalence
> 1 < 2 ~ 3    // same as 1 < (2 ~ 3), because Equivalence > Comparative
> 1 += 2 ~ 3   // same as 1 += (2 ~ 3), because Equivalence > Comparative > Assignment
> 1 ... 2 ~ 3  // error, because Range and Equivalence are unrelated
> ```

Although in your case, as it appears that your operator is used for multiplication, you could simply use the standard library's `MultiplicationPrecedence` group, which is used for the `*` operator:

```
infix operator × : MultiplicationPrecedence
```

It is defined as:

```
precedencegroup MultiplicationPrecedence {
  associativity: left
  higherThan: AdditionPrecedence
}
```

For a full list of standard library precedence groups, as well as more info about this change, see the [evolution proposal](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0077-operator-precedence.md).