# Operations should no longer be declared with body

Tags: swift

I'm getting this error when trying to convert some Swift 2.x code to Swift 3.x. I've read some posts like this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39036113/swift3-how-to-handle-precedencegroup-now-operator-should-be-declare-with-a-bod) and the [proposal](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0077-operator-precedence.md) but I don't seem to get it.

```
infix operator - { associativity left precedence 160 }
```

What I've tried:

```
precedencegroup Additive {
    associativity: left
    higherThan: MultiplicationPrecedence
}
```

Is this right?

Comment: Isn't operator `-` defined by default with right precedence group? And there's system Additive precedence group already too. Also, why your Additive has higher priority than Multiplicative? [You should check that out](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations).

Comment: Well, I was converting the code from https://github.com/inFullMobile/WobbleView and since Multiplicative has a precedence of 150, I thought `precedence 160` translates into `higherThan: MultiplicationPrecendence`.